# Global conformally flat coordinates

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, conformal-geometry

I know that for a 2D manifold there can allways be found a local chart such that the metric is conformally flat. Is it possible globally? If the manifold is simply connected, like a disk, does it make it possible then? I'll be happy to see how it can be prove or a counter example.
Thanks very much!

Comment: This is the classical uniformization theorem of Koebe:  Any simply-connected, non-compact, connected Riemann surface is conformally equivalent to either the whole complex plane or to the unit disk.

Comment: Great! It is exactly what I need. Thank you!